# Restrict jQuery event only on some text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this jQuery which automatically adds a dot on thousand:

```
  $(function () {

         $(document).on("keyup", "input[type=text]", function () {

                if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

                  // format number
                  $(this).val(function (index, value) {
                     return value

                  //doadaje tacku na hiljade:
                    .replace(/\D/g, "")
                    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "\.")                             
                    ;

                  });
          })
   })
```

On my form I have one textbox for date and all others textboxes are for numerical input. I want to restrict this jQuery to works only with textboxes for numerical input. Now this jQuery formatting and textbox for date but I don't want to do that on that field.

Comment: How do you identify the textbox is for numerical input?

Comment: Each textbox has his own ID name.

Comment: How about `input[type=text]:not(#textboxid)`?

Comment: I've tried that but I got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each textbox has his own ID name

I will rather suggest to use an identifier to distinguish between inputs which will accept only number. Then use this class to trigger event

```
$(function () {
   $(document).on("keyup", "input[class=onlyNum]", function () {
            //Rest of code
             })
       })
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/1w0L9re4/)

Comment: That  is exactly what I wanted. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can access to input by class

$(document).on("keyup", "input[type=text]", function () {